# How to get last 4 digit of number in android?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain mobile number edit text in which user can edit mobile number and I have to send two request to server like:- mobile number and mssdn,mobile number(which is full lenghth ) and mssdn(which contain mobile number last 4 digit).How can I do that

Comment: What are to trying to achieve?! Just the last 4 digit of contact number? If that's the case thn check the length of the string and extract last 4 characters

Comment: no I want when user enter mobile number then I have to full mobile number with last 4 digit of that mobile number to server

Comment: Can you please be little more precise. You are making no sense to wm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this. Check for length greater than 4 before calling subString to avoid IndexOutOfBounds Exception.

```
    EditText mEdtPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPhoneNumber);
    String phoneNumber = mEdtPhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();
    String strLastFourDi = phoneNumber.length() >= 4 ? phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length() - 4): "";
```

Also what is mssdn?? Is it msisdn??

Answer (score 2):

Use the modulus (%) operator:

**To get the last digit:** use `number % 10`

**To get the last 2 digits:** use `number % 100`

and so on

For example:
 `42455%10000 = 2455`

Comment: Cleaver idea! I haven't thought about that, but it's not always a good approach to treat a phone number as integer. For using the modulus operator you need the phone number to be represented as an integer, but the limit of an integer can easily be exceeded in that way. Thus, it's better to use a String and **subString()** the desired part of the number.

Comment: @TodorKostov You are right, I thought that OP intended it as an integer since he didn't specify the type :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
    EditText phoneNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberEditText);
    String phoneNumber = phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString();
    String lastFourDigits = phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length() - 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use regex because this will only give you result if the last four letters are actually numbers on the other hand the `substring` function simply give you last four letters no matter they are `numbers` or `characters`. e.g **4344sdsdss4** will give you **dss4** which is clearly not a part of phone number

```
    String str="4444ntrjntkr555566";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})$");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
      if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(m.groupCount()));
      }
```

this will produce 5566

Working

> //d mean digits
>
> {4} for fix length as 4
>
> $ mean at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Integer> f(String str){
        ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();
        if (null == str || str.length() < 4){
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "there are less than 4 digits");
            return digits;
        }
        String digitsStr = str.substring(str.length() - 4);
        for (char c : digitsStr.toCharArray()){
            try {
                Integer digit = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
                digits.add(digit);
            } catch (Exception e){
                continue;
            }
        }
        return digits;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use a new method introduced in kotlin: takeLast(n)

```
fun getLastDigit(data: String, n:Int): String {
    return if(data.length > n){
        data.takeLast(n)
    }else {
        ""
    }
}
```